# Sending Dynamic query params in mulesoft HTTP Request

Tags: mule-esb

I have a requirement where I have to send Dynamic query params on demand while sending it http request in mulesoft.

I am writing an expression to handle such scenario

something like this-

if(message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.param1 != null)

flowVars.params.put("param1", message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.param1);

if(message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.param2 != null)

flowVars.params.put("param2", message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.param2);

if(message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.param3 != null)

flowVars.params.put("param3", message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.param3);

//if it is a mandatory

flowVars.params.put("api_key", flowVars.apikey);

Creating hashmap but it failing in expression itself

can anyone help me on this

any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to set up an initial `java.util.HashMap` in a variable. Try something like this:

```
<set-variable variableName="params" value="#[new java.util.HashMap()]" mimeType="application/java" doc:name="Set params"/>
 <expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[if(message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.param1 != null)
    flowVars.params.put("param1", message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.param1);
]]></expression-component>
        <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/yourPath" method="{METHOD}" doc:name="HTTP {METHOD}">
            <http:request-builder>
                <http:query-params expression="#[flowVars.params]"/>
                <http:header headerName="${header.correlationid}" value="#[sessionVars.correlationId]"/>
            </http:request-builder>
        </http:request>
```